# Running HTML5 with Database in Android WebView

Tags: android-webview, android-sqlite, dynamic-programming

I am developing an app with html5 pages locally stored in the assets folder. I have included a database with some php scripts, is it still possible to run in WebView?

Comment: php scripts? what you mean?

Comment: At the moment am developing database using php and mySql, planning on integrating it with the Html.

Answer (score 2):

for using database in webView you have two ways:

1) use localStorage that you should handle it by javaScript

2) use java database,for that you need javaScriptInterFace() that provide you a bridge between javaScript and java class. and create java database then put your data in it or read from it

**see [this link](https://github.com/didimoo/AndroidLocalStorage) it will help you**-(this link show you how use java database like browser localStorage)

Comment: Any links to javaScript tutorial for developing database or better, a demo?

Comment: I add link,check it please

Comment: Thanks, will check out the all the options.

Answer (score 0):

No not at all you can not run a **php** in a `webview`  it can understand only html ,CSS and JavaScript just like a browser.

**Suggestion 1:**

If you want to build a HTML page using your local database you could do that using java no need of php.

Just fetch the data from db then build HTML page by concatenating java strings with the data,HTML mark up,CSS and javascript then load the resulting HTML page in webview

If you want to access Java function from JavaScript you could use **addjavascriptinterface** of java.

The java function can be anything like a function that inserts or updates data into local dB or a function that returns a data from local db

It can also produce dynamic html content locally jus like a dynamic web language like php,classic asp etc..

**Suggestion 2:**

If you want to do it using php then you have to host it in the internet server along with db and load the page URL in webview

Comment: Ok, now how do i create a database and also be able to get data from it.

Comment: In android you could use cursors to load data from local db.In android we would use sqlite instead of Mysql.you can easily create sqlie db.just Google how to create local sqlite db ? How to consume add update data in android ? Its that simple.